Selenium - Powershell - Find css style
I have a web UI which has a video feed on it that sometimes takes a second or two to load.  I've determined that the only difference in the particular web element is as follows:
Not loaded:
<canvas id="canvasplayer_0" style="position: absolute; display: none; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 448px; height: 335px;" width="704" height="480"></canvas>

Loaded:
<canvas id="canvasplayer_0" style="position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 448px; height: 335px;" width="704" height="480"></canvas>

Note, the difference is that before the feed loads, 'display' is 'none', and once it loads, 'display' is 'block'.
Querying for that particular id existing is easy.  However, what I am trying to figure out is how, via $wait.Until, I can query for that id, but wait for the display to change from none to block.  I would assume it has to be done via CSS Selector, but I am not finding any good way of doing so.

You can use CSS selectors,
#canvasplayer_0[style*='display: block']

vs
#canvasplayer_0[style*='display: none']


Jeff, would the syntax be: $ChromeDriver.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::cssSelector(#canvasplayer_0[style*='display: block') ????

No idea. I don't typically use PS for Selenium stuff but I know CSS selectors. Did you check the docs? You just asked for a CSS selector to find the element.

All good, Jeff.  Thanks again.
